# How to access a parameterised constructor of a super class from sub class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to access calculate() method of superclass using parameterised constructor where I just want the area and not volume, but instead of this, I end up accessing subclass calculate() which is producing o/p as 0. How do I resolve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Shape
{
    double length, breadth;

    Shape(double l, double b)
    {
        length = l;
        breadth = b;
    }

    Shape(double len)
    {
        length = len;
        breadth = len;
    }

    double calculate()
    {
        return length * breadth;
    }
}

public class Test1 extends Shape
{
    double height;

    Test1(double x, double y)
    {
        super(x, y);
    }

    Test1(double p, double q, double r)
    {
        //super(2.0);
        height = r;
        length = p;
        breadth = q;
    }

    double calculate()
    {
        return length * breadth * height;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test1 myshape1 = new Test1(2, 4);
        Test1 myshape2 = new Test1(2, 3, 4);
        double volume1;
        double volume2;
        volume1 = myshape1.calculate();
        volume2 = myshape2.calculate();
        System.out.println(volume1);
        System.out.println(volume2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the constructors have to do with `calculate`? What is the **exact** input, what is the exact expected vs. actual output and why do you *think* the code should behave differently?

Comment: Why would you code it this way?  If you want area _and_ volume why not make two different methods and override the specific implementation of them in the specific classes that extend shape if they are different, such as a `Circle`.  Your question does not really make sense.

Comment: On a semantics note, it is possible to call `super.calculate()` to refer to a parent class implemention. For cases of multiple inheritance, you can specify which parent class / interface: `Shape.super.calculate()`. That said, the use case here is a little strange.

Answer (score 2):

These class names are confusing. What is `shape` really? Given that you're calculating an area which is equal to `length * breadth`, it's likely just a rectangle.

`Test1` is, I guess, a cuboid.

What do you want the height to be if you haven't specified it? A cuboid has a height. You can't calculate it's area (`length * breadth`) since it does not make sense for a 3D object. The total surface area, or the area of a single surface, maybe...

If you want a rectangle, instantiate a rectangle. If you'd rather the height not default to zero then use a different default like 1.

Here's how I would write it:

```
class Rectangle
{
    final double length, width;

    Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
}

class Cuboid extends Rectangle
{
    final double height;

    Cuboid(double length, double width, double height)
    {
        super(length, width);
        this.height = height;
    }

    Cuboid(double length, double width)
    {
        this(length, width, 1);
    }

    double volume()
    {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Cuboid myshape1 = new Cuboid(2, 4);
        Cuboid myshape2 = new Cuboid(2, 3, 4);
        double volume1;
        double volume2;
        volume1 = myshape1.volume();
        volume2 = myshape2.volume();
        System.out.println(volume1);
        System.out.println(volume2);
    }
}
```

Comment: For a 2D shape in a 3D class, I'd argue for a height of 0 since that results in a volume of 0. But overall this unnecessarily restricts you to having dimensions coupled to specific fields, without any enforcement of them. A better way imo is a three-coordinate point, and using two of those to build the cuboid unambiguously

Comment: @Rogue I think the whole introduction of inheritance here is a bit questionable tbh. A cuboid is not a rectangle, unless you're counting when viewed from a specific position (in this case, above/below). So yes, when I said this is "how I would write it" I was somewhat exaggerating. But anyway, provided that you are only calculating volumes, the 3 dimensions are a fine representation. You don't need a coordinate system until you're talking about objects with respect to some reference point. Overkill.

Comment: It boils down to if you want to consider an object that's 1x1x2 the same as an object that is 2x1x1. At face value, they're not; but anyone can see how they would be. Mathematically, a rectangle is a cuboid with a 0-valued third dimension (something that, like 2D objects, doesn't really exist in our 3D world). The three coordinate suggestion was just a suggestion to an alternative (building on your answer), I'm actually agreeing with what you've written above as a solution.

Comment: Also the original question is made more confusing by the _two_ constructors from `Test1`. Ambiguity kills.

Comment: Although this answer is helpful and illustrates how the op should have approached the problem, it doesn't address op's question of how to "access calculate() method of superclass"

Answer (score 1):

When you extends a class, and overwrite a method, you are saying it's a children responsability to implement the functionality. So, you can't access the parent function outside the children class. Solution would be to change myshape1 class to Shape instead of Teste1. Otherwise you have to change your method. Note also that you are not using your superclass(which is the objective of inheritance), once you reimplemented almost all methods. I would do it like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Shape{
   double length, breadth;
   public Shape(double l, double b){   
      length = l;
      breadth= b;
    }
  public Shape(double len){ 
     length = len;
     breadth = len;
   }
  double calculate(){  
    return length * breadth ;

  }
}
public class Test1 extends Shape{
    double height;
    public Test1(double x, double y){
        super(x,y);
        height = 1d;
    }

    public Test1(double p, double q, double r){
        super(p, q);
        height=r;
    }
    double calculate()
    {
        return super.calculate()*height;
    }
public static void main(String args[]){

    Test1 myshape1 = new Test1(2,4);
    Test1 myshape2 = new Test1(2,3,4);
    double volume1;
    double volume2;
    volume1 = myshape1.calculate();
    volume2=myshape2.calculate();
    System.out.println(volume1);
    System.out.println(volume2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, you can access any inherited methods within the class via `super` calls. Which confuses me because you say you can't, then you use it in your code example. __Edit:__ I got grammar trapped, I see what you're saying now